# How to ineractively adjust 2 Divs in a row

Tags: html, css

I try to display 2 images side by side - 50/50, in such a way that with a mouse I can move divider stretching one image and shrinking another.

Here is a code I try to achieve this goal, but it doesn't work as expected.
(this is part of Dash)

```
app.layout = html.Div(id = 'mainTestDiv',
    children = [html.Div(id = 'win1',
        children = [html.Img(src = "http://dummyimage.com/1280x500/00f/fff", id = 'pic1',
            className = 'img100')],
        className = 'mtest'),

    html.Div(id = 'win2',
        children = html.Img(id = 'pic2', src = "http://dummyimage.com/1280x500/f0f/fff",
            className = 'img100'),
        className = 'mtest2')
    ],
    className = 'my_test_container'
)
```

and here is css that goes with it.

```
.my_test_container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px red;
    /* not sure why but I don't get black background either*/
    background-color: #111111;
}

.mtest {
    resize: horizontal;
    width: 50vw;
    overflow: auto;
}

.mtest2 {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}

.img100 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

If I hide right Div `(id = 'win2')` with `"display: none;"` left image reacts correctly (as intended), means I can smoothly shrink image to almost zero on left end of the screen, and stretch it to 100% at the right end of the screen.
Adding right image causes some odd behavior. How can I fix that?

Edit: I expect to be able to move divider smoothly to either end shrinking one image and expanding the other to 95-100% of the screen width.

What I get is after clicking to move divider, it jumps instantly to the left about 30% (shrinking left image) - no mouse move. Then I can shrink left image as intended (right image takes almost the whole screen width) but can not move divider to the right of the screen - it stops at about 50% and doesn't want to move any further, leaving both images in view. I tried different combinations of setting and none seems to work for me.

Comment: "...causes some odd behavior" is not very descriptive. Maybe try harder to articulate the behavior you're seeing vs. the behavior you want to see.

Comment: I will edit main question.